# Making good use of analytics data in mod-tools

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools, data-analysis, analytics

I'm a pro-tem mod at the beta gardening.SE site and while I was going through the analytics data, especially the "Search keywords" (which I interpret to mean *"what people typed in their search engine to get to this site"*), I found quite a few interesting and on-topic searches for which there are no questions on the site. Presumably these people were directed here from a random search, and most likely left unsatisfied, because they couldn't find what they were looking for.

Now, questions (and answers) on some of those search terms would be a great addition to the site, and I'd like to take some of those and frame questions. Unfortunately, I (or the other mods) can't possibly ask all those questions and besides, I don't know enough about some of them to even ask a question. Also, it would amount to giving the mods an unfair advantage as only we have access to the data. This brings me to my question (rather, a suggestion):

> Can we filter down the searches terms and share some of the really interesting ones with the community and solicit questions/answers from people who are knowledgable in those areas? Perhaps a fortnightly/monthly meta post?

I believe this is a good way to build the site, especially in the beta stage, as you're using data to actively fix areas where you're deficient. So the next person to google a similar phrase and reach us will (hopefully) have a positive experience from the site. This probably might not be a feasible idea for well established sites, whereas for budding sites, it can go a long way.

Comment: Note: Your search terms [may include keywords from other stack-exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92915/strange-results-in-search-keywords-analytics)

Comment: Of course, which is why I said a _few_ were interesting and I wanted to share only the _filtered_ search terms.

Comment: No good pun should go unnoticed: "budding sites". ;-)  But suggesting these terms as question fodder on meta.* sounds like an idea worth cultivating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably OK **post on your meta for feedback**, with some of the relevant keywords you found, and asking if anyone is interested in asking a *real, actual, genuine* question on one of those topics.

To be 100% clear, I *absolutely do not* support this being used as a synthetic way to drive traffic!

I only think it's OK if it is posted on meta as a "nudge" to see if others in the community have a "eureka!" or "hey, I do have a question about that.." related to those particular keywords that they'd like to share.

Comment: This isn't to drive traffic, rather to captivate the traffic that comes here on its own. But your point is taken.