# Site analytics in StackOverflow en español shows an unknown referring site

Tags: discussion, site-analytics

I've just earned the privilege to view this data and I noticed that the list of referring sites was surprising:

[image]

The first referring site is evillegast.github.io, but that site does not exist.

Nevertheless I found a github account (https://github.com/evillegast/) which could be the source, but it seems to be an unfinished CV web template, so ...

How reliable are those numbers? I know that they are an approximation <sup>1</sup> but it is hard to believe that hundreds of clicks were done from [this page](https://github.com/evillegast/WebDevelopment/blob/7a9897b77e20bf7a24561026f997ed69ee6c6cea/hobbies.html)

<sup>1</sup> I mean, all these 438, 438*2, 438*3 ... visits are clearly *rounded off* in some way

Comment: [The privileges page](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) says _The numbers are [sampled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121423/209901) so it's not uncommon to see implausible results such as several search engines at exactly 211 visits_. I think it also applies to referrals, since they come in blocks which sounds suspicious.