# Inaccurate visit count for referring sites

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, statistics, site-visits

Inaccurate visit count for referring sites.

Example from https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources

[image]

Also saw some 441 on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources and https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources

Comment: Does this answer your question? This post is linked from the privilege page regarding site analytics as to why these numbers appear: [Analytics search keywords are unreliable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121423/analytics-search-keywords-are-unreliable)

Comment: @Glorfindel and sonic thanks!